# Tracking location in background causes app rejection

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Recently I submitted an app in the app store that tracks the users location, send that to a server and that location is then visible on another service outside of the app store. The origional submition of the app with this feature was approved, then I made an update with some bug fixes and it was first rejected with this reasoning

> Your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your 
>   Info.plist file but does not declare any features that require
>   persistent location. Apps that declare support for location in the
>   UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file must have features that
>   require persistent location.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to include features that require the persistent
>   use of real-time location updates while the app is in the background.
>   Please also add the following battery use disclaimer in your
>   Application Description: "Continued use of GPS running in the
>   background can dramatically decrease battery life."

so I added in `Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life.` to my app description and also made a tester note as to what we use the background location for

> Background Location is used for tracking the drivers location so that dispatch can view where the driver is.

I then resumbitted and got another rejection this time saying

> Thank you for your resubmission. Based on the response in the review notes >section, your app uses background location mode for the purpose of tracking >employees only, which is not appropriate for the App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to include additional features for your users
>   that require the persistent use of real-time location updates while
>   the app is in the background. For example, a map in the user interface
>   that allows drivers to see their location.
>
> If tracking your employees’s locations is your only intended use of
>   background location, it would be more appropriate to distribute and
>   sell your app as a custom B2B app, through the Volume Purchase
>   Program.

This rejection makes no sense to me, there are hundreds of apps that do exactly what we are doing like `Uber` or `Lyft`. Their location gets sent to a server and drivers are visible on the map, only difference being is the map that they are visible on is not an app in the app store.

So my question is how do I get an app in the app store that racks the users location, sends that location to a server to allow the position being visible on another service of ours?

Comment: This seems pretty clear cut. Uber/Lyft etc allow normal users to see the locations of the cars being tracked. Who can see your locations? If it's just employees of some sort, the B2B suggestion is correct. If the public can, via a web site etc, then you should explain that use better to the reviewers. I'd include a link to where they can see the locations in use.

Comment: @DaveWood the reviewer does not suggest that it has to be publicly accessible though. B2B is not practical solution for this at all because this is not a company app. our company offers a service for other companies to use so they need a login to access stuff. Managing all these different devices would be extremely cumbersome as it could be thousands of devices

Comment: B2B doesn't require you to manage devices. It's just a different app store. If anyone can sign up for the service, create a demo account for the reviewer and include the login information with the submission. There are fields specifically for that when submitting.

Comment: @DaveWood you mean the other service that you can see the vehicle locations on? I already give them a login for the app stoe application

Comment: Does that login let them view locations? That's what they're having an issue with, so that's what they need to see. Sometimes you have to really spell the use case out for them in excruciating detail so they get it.

Comment: the login information I give them is just for the app that does not allow them to view the location. the other service (a website) would allow them to view it which I do not supply them with because I did not think that was necessary

Comment: That's what's necessary to convince them the app should be on the App Store and not moved to the B2B store. Good luck!

Comment: @DaveWood ok thank you very much!

Comment: @tyczj any updates on that? Have you found solution?

Comment: @tyczj, did you manage to finally publish the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that according to apple the only way to have it pass is to add a map so the user can visibly see their location, so thats what I did and they passed it

Comment: can you explain in more detail how you fixed it?

Comment: Just like the answers says, I added a mapview to the app and thats it